# Deploy ASP.Net site to windows server

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, amazon-web-services

I have been developing an ASP application which I have almost finished. It accesses a SQL database on a Windows sever on AWS. I would like to deploy my application to AWS though.

Does anyone have any suggestions about how I should do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to the [Deploying an asp.net application](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=359297) thread that contains all necessary information and step-by-step instructions on how to accomplish this task.

Answer (score 0):

If you are deploying an MVC application, check whether the hosting provider provides the support for MVC hosting. Just right-click on the solution and select Publish. Then copy the files into the hosting space.